# Return array elements larger than a number

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return (element >= 10);
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

How can I return values that are larger than (or equal to) a number other than `10`? For example, `array.filter(isBigEnough(15))` would give me `44, 130`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2722159/1176601

Comment: _"Also i would like to put loops in the function"_ - What do you mean by that? It doesn't make sense to put loops in your `isBigEnough()` function if you are using it as a callback for `filter()`.

Comment: Sorry for my English, meant a totally different thing. After review, I removed this sentence

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Functions are first-class citizens in JS, so you can create a function which returns another function:

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return function(element, index, array) {
    return (element >= value);
  }
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough(10));
```